# BOOST xml_oarchive memory access error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, xml-serialization

I am trying to learn boost::serialization to make a same game system, and I got pretty far with the text_oarchive format. I learned how to use BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID for polymorphic classes and use BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP for xml archives. Then, when I tried to combine them, using polymorphic classes with the xml_oarchive archive format, I got a runtime error.

The error: [image]

My code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>

struct base {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    //...
    // only required when using method 1 below
    // no real serialization required - specify a vestigial one
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version){}

    virtual ~base() { }
};

struct derived : public base {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    int i = 93894;


    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int file_version){
        // method 1 : invoke base class serialization
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this));

        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(i);
    }

    virtual ~derived() { }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(derived, "derived")


int main()
{

    std::ofstream ofstr("file.txt");
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oarch(ofstr);

    base* b = new derived();
    oarch << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);

    std::cin.get();

    delete b;
}
```

All this runs beautifully with the text_oarchive format, but when I change it to the xml_oarchive it crashes.

What am I doing wrong here, it seems I did everything the tutorials told me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the problem. It didn't have to do with the polymorphism at all.

The problem was with this line

```
ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this));
```

The problem with this is that `boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this)` doesn't have a variable name, which it uses to resolve the name of the XML tag. When i changed the exact same code to:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("owner", boost::serialization::base_object<base>(*this));
```

Which explicitly makes a nvp using the make_nvp method. This way it is given a name, instead of trying to figure it out from a name that doesn't exist.